# ORA-22993: specified input amount is greater than actual source amount while creating table with WITH DATA CLAUSE

Tags: database, oracle, aggregate, create-table, with-statement

I need to concatenate the job message descriptions by ett_date and create a new table. After this I am going to operate a different step. My problem is that while i am  creating table with WITH DATA CLAUSE, I am getting ORA-22993: specified input amount is greater than actual source amount error. Could you help me about how to solve this problem ?

```
create table mytable as
WITH DATA AS(
SELECT 
ett_date,JOB_NAME,PLAN_NAME,JOB_PERSON1_INFO,JOB_PERSON2_INFO,JOB_PROCEDURE
  ,RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e,REGEXP_REPLACE(job_message_desc, '[^0-9A-Za-z]', ' ')  , ' ',',').EXTRACT('//text()')).getCLOBVal() ,',') a
   from mytable group by ett_date,JOB_NAME,PLAN_NAME,JOB_PERSON1_INFO,JOB_PERSON2_INFO,JOB_PROCEDURE)
  select *from DATA
```

Comment: Do you expect `column a` to be `varchar2` in your new table `mytable` ?

Comment: No  i expect clob

Comment: Try to remove WITH clause: `create table mytable as
  select *from (
SELECT 
ett_date,JOB_NAME,PLAN_NAME,JOB_PERSON1_INFO,JOB_PERSON2_INFO,JOB_PROCEDURE
  ,RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e,REGEXP_REPLACE(job_message_desc, '[^0-9A-Za-z]', ' ')  , ' ',',').EXTRACT('//text()')).getCLOBVal() ,',') a
   from mytable group by ett_date,JOB_NAME,PLAN_NAME,JOB_PERSON1_INFO,JOB_PERSON2_INFO,JOB_PROCEDURE)`

Comment: when i tried it i got ORA-22993: specified input amount is greater than actual source amount error

Comment: Probable a typo - `create table mytable as ... SELECT ... from mytable` -> *ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object*

Comment: i realized it then i changed it while executing the statement. the error is still the same

Comment: Can you please try following code: `create table mytable as select *from ( SELECT ett_date,JOB_NAME,PLAN_NAME,JOB_PERSON1_INFO,JOB_PERSON2_INFO,JOB_PROCEDURE ,RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e,REGEXP_REPLACE(job_message_desc, '[^0-9A-Za-z]', ' ') , ' ',',').EXTRACT('//text()')).getCLOBVal() ,',') a from mytable  WHERE JOB_MESSAGE_DESC IS NOT NULL group by ett_date,JOB_NAME,PLAN_NAME,JOB_PERSON1_INFO,JOB_PERSON2_INFO,JOB_PROCEDURE)`

Comment: i tried it and got ORA-22993: specified input amount is greater than actual source amount error